# Tomcat blocking PUT requests

Tags: rest, tomcat

I have two tomcats running on same machine.

- Tom 1 (https enabled):

  ```
  Connector Port - 80,
  SSL Port - 443,
  Shutdown port- 8005,
  AJP port - 8009,
  Redirect Port - 8443
  ```
- Tom 2 (http only):

  ```
  Connector Port - 8090,
  Shutdown port- 9005,
  AJP port - 9009,
  Redirect Port - 9443,
  ```

Tom1 Runs as expected. But Tom2 is blocking only the PUT requests but accepts all POST and GET payload.

Why is this so? Do you see any flaws in Tomcat's port configurations?

Comment: you might have to add more detail like What response you get for PUT API call, sample request/response headers, console log...

Comment: I have 3 consecutive requests. 1st request ( POST ) is for login. 2nd request (POST) is for Creating an Application . 3rd request(PUT) is for updating the previously created application. Here, first two requests are working fine but 3rd request is giving 401 (unauthorized error).....Session Expiry is not the issue.